# how to change database content into multilanguage in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, multilingual

I want to change database content into other language depending on chosen language. In the database data store in english. All the static text is changing to other language like portuguese, french etc. by using .po file. But I want change the database content aswell.

Please give me solution...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

see the documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html#translate

since you did not specify your cake version or gave any other more specific scenario or code examples, I am not able to go into any more detail here